# Convert Hexa To decimal numbers

Tags: excel

When I put 15 digits number in my excel cell it converts it in to`1.002E+15`. How do I put it back to 15 digits number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a matter of display, your number is not converted.

Right-click the cell, select "Format cells...", select "Number" and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

- Just right click on the cell
- Select `Format Cells...`
- In Number tab, Select Number in Category
- and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Also, you can set Decimal places: to 0 if you don't want it.